# Spring - POST parameters with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I'm trying to make an AJAX call using plain javascript to a Spring controller.
The call fails with "Required String parameter 'allowedRoles' is not present"

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/updateRoles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateRoles(@RequestParam("allowedRoles") String allowedRoles, 
final Map<String, Object> model) {

    return "services";
}
```

And the AJAX call:

```
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("POST", "/services/updateRoles", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send({"allowedRoles":allowedRoles});
```

I have also tried

```
xhttp.send("allowedRoles=" + allowedRoles);
```

But the result is the same

Comment: You aren't sending a parameter you are sending a request body.

Comment: @M.Deinum And how do I send parameters?

Answer (score 1):

try it with JSON:

```
//Create JSON data
var jsonData = {allowedRoles: 'string allowed'};
var formattedJsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
//Send it
xhttp.send(formattedJsonData);
```

If you want, you can check your data to be sure that jsonData is correct, ie:

```
  console.log(jsonData);
  console.log(JSON.parse(formattedJsonData));
```